# Failure to sign in error after exporting signed apk

Tags: java, android, google-play, multiplayer, google-play-games

I am developing an app that uses google's turn based multiplayer API. I have two devices that I am using to test on. The first phone, which uses the developer gmail, can sign into the multiplayer just fine. The second one, whether I install the app directly from the computer or I install the signed apk with the release keystore, gets this error every time I try to sign in with it:

**Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again.**

The second phone uses a gmail account that is set as a testing account for the app in the developer console. I am not positive what the issue is here. And yes, I have made sure that there is not an actual network issue as I am able access the internet just fine.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you publish apk for testing? It takes some time after that to be available for testing devices.

Comment: If you use proguard, keep all gmail related class files.

Comment: @MagicalPhoenix I just did everything the documentation I am following says to do. It's in the alpha stage but all I have done is upload the apk.

Comment: @challa I am not using proguard unless eclipse automatically implements it when exporting the signed apk.

Comment: @saboehnke Then now use proguard and use below code -keep class javamail.** {*;}
-keep class javax.mail.** {*;}
-keep class javax.activation.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.dsn.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.handlers.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.smtp.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.util.** {*;}
-keep class mailcap.** {*;}
-keep class mimetypes.** {*;}
-keep class myjava.awt.datatransfer.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.awt.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.misc.** {*;}

Comment: @challa Ok I will give that a shot. But is this required for this? All of the tutorials that I used said nothing about this so I am just making sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After troubleshooting for a while I realized that my issue was that my SHA1 fingerprint for my signed apk and the SHA1 fingerprint for the project that I had setup in my google developer console were different. To fix this I just unlinked the application from my game and relinked it using the correct SHA1 fingerprint.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio 1.0? I ask because I think the locations of where the keystores for signing have been reordered?

Comment: I use eclipse which allows me to just export by using my release keystore or it lets me create the keystore where I want it and then lets me use that to export the apk using the release keystore